# UIRefreshControl stucks in last dragging step

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uikit, uirefreshcontrol

Pulling down the the refresh control and initiating the related process work fine so far. The problem is that the last step to fill the the UIActivityIndicator doesn't go very smooth like in Mail.app. One has to pull even a bit more to start the refreshing process.

[image]

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Same problem here, there is a 40pt offset jump as well :/ I am using UICollectionView thought...

Answer (score -1):

What you have to do is actually "end" the refreshing function by calling the endRefreshing method:

```
- (void)refreshView:(UIRefreshControl *)sender {
    [self updateProfile]; //do something...in my case it updates a profile
    [sender endRefreshing];
}
```

Comment: Jep, I do this with ReactiveCocoa. So, the "end" is not the problem.

Comment: your answer does not relate to the questions